# Are there tools / techniques to debug jQuery event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firebug, jquery-events

I am currently trying to figure out what click event handlers have attached to my div.  There should only be one handler attached, but there appears to be at least one.  I'm using FireBug but Chrome could be an option as well.  I don't like IE so I'd prefer not to use that.

The best case scenario is that I can inspect my div using FireBug, and see a list of event handlers.

Comment: i like this question and one up more ma side

Comment: someone just posted a bookmarklet that allows you to see the eventhandlers attached to a function. I think it's pretty awesome.  http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

Comment: I think these answers are all great.  I will pick my most favorite later today, and sum up the responses in a follow up edit.  Please keep posting!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) is a nice javascript bookmark you can run on a page to see all the events that are attached to a control.

Comment: it still does not seem to reveal the function which is really handling the event, and only shows that jquery is somehow listening

Answer (score 10):

If you are using jQuery to assign your event handlers you can locate the attached events via  `$("div").data("events");`

```
$("div.test").each(function(){
    var events = $(this).data("events");
    //events.click will give you a list of click handlers, events.mouseenter, etc..
    $.each(events, function(i, eventType){
        $.each(eventType, function(){
          //this.handler() can be used to find the anonymous function assigned to the element.
          $("body").append("<h1>" + this.type + "</h1>");
        });
    });
});
```

If you wish to get live handlers you can do the same thing for the document.

```
var liveEvents = $(document).data("events").live;
$.each(liveEvents, function() {
    $("body").append("<h1>" + this.selector + this.origType +  "</h1>");
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b24Vy/2/).

Comment: This does not seem to work with jQuery 1.10.  After `$(element).on("custom-event", function() { console.log("hi"); })` if I inspect `$(element).data('events')` I get `undefined`, but `$(element).trigger("custom-event")` triggers that callback.

Answer (score 8):

Install fireQuery plugin for firebug and you will see all jQuery-attached events in the firebug display, just like you wish ;)

You can find it here: http://firequery.binaryage.com/ or here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firequery/

It will make your firebug look like this:
[image]

Comment: I wish there was this for Chrome

Answer (score 6):

Check out the $.data function.

Specifically something like this:

var clicks = $(mySelector).data('events').click;

Should return a list of click event handlers and their associated DOM objects.

Answer (score -2):

"fire-bug" Add-ons (for mozilla) is the best option for this.

Comment: `The best case scenario is that I can inspect my div using FireBug, and see a list of event handlers.`

Comment: I've installed firebug and have been using it.  What next?

Comment: I poked around and I don't believe there is a way to view attached events just by looking at the DOM element in firebug, as MedicineMan wants to do.  Break points would only help once the events are fired.  He wants to see what is attached at any given time.