# Keep row visible when confirm dialog returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

Hi I have a table containing rows. When page loads I am hiding the rows with odd numbers (they contain details). When I click the row (even number) it display the next row (the row with details).
please see the jsfiddle example.

#### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Faisal</td>
        <td>Applicaiton Developer</td>
        <td>Work in  Aid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">this is Faisal Details</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Approve" class="approve" />
            <input type="button" value="Deny" class="deny" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancel" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fabrizio </td>
        <td>Applicaiton Developer</td>
        <td>Work in  Aid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">this is Fabrizio </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Approve" class="approve" />
            <input type="button" value="Deny" class="deny" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="deny" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kelly </td>
        <td>Applicaiton Developer</td>
        <td>Work in Aid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">this is Kelly </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Approve" class="approve" />
            <input type="button" value="Deny" class="deny" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="deny" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hillary </td>
        <td>Applicaiton Developer</td>
        <td>Work in  Aid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">this is Hillary </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Approve" class="approve" />
            <input type="button" value="Deny" class="deny" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="deny" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Krista </td>
        <td>Applicaiton Developer</td>
        <td>Work in Aid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">this is Krista </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Approve" class="approve" />
            <input type="button" value="Deny" class="deny" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="deny" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Justin </td>
        <td>Applicaiton Developer</td>
        <td>Work in  Aid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">this is Justin </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Approve" class="approve" />
            <input type="button" value="Deny" class="deny" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="deny" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eric </td>
        <td>Applicaiton Developer</td>
        <td>Work Aid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">this is Eric </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Approve" class="approve" />
            <input type="button" value="Deny" class="deny" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="deny" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Faisal </td>
        <td>Applicaiton Developer</td>
        <td>Work inAid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">this is Faisal Details</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Approve" class="approve" />
            <input type="button" value="Deny" class="deny" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="deny" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### jquery:

```
$("table tr:nth-child(odd)").css("display", "none");
var prevRowIndex;
$("table tr:not(:first-child)").click(function (e) {

    if (prevRowIndex != undefined) {

        $(prevRowIndex).css("display", "none");
        prevRowIndex = null;
    }
    var styles = {
        "border": "#000",
            "margin-bottom": "10px"
    };
    prevRowIndex = $(this).next();
    //$(this).css("z-index", "9999");

    $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
});
$(".approve").click(function (e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you would like to approve this request?") == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents("tr").css("display", "block");
    }
});
$(".deny").click(function (e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you would like to deny this request?") == false) {
        $(this).parents("tr").css("display", "block");
        e.preventDefault();

    }
});
$(".cancel").click(function (e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you would like to cancel this request?") == false) {
        $(this).parents("tr").css("display", "block");
        e.preventDefault();

    }
});
```

When a button is click (which is inside the detail row), it first ask for confirmation.
My issue is when I select "cancel" in the confirmation dialog box, it hides the details row.

I hope I had explained it properly. Any help on this is appreciated.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/L5mzU/3/)

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question and stop trying to get around having to do so.

Comment: I am having issue linking to jsfiddle...

Comment: Because it requires you to include code. Copy the relevant code from your fiddle in the question and remove the left spacing and ticks and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I really appreciate it.

Comment: no problem. For these issues, take a look at firebug's debugger. i can only imagine that the answer came because someone either saw it, or used the debugger and some breakpoints to follow the process. Also, look at the [third answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198108/are-there-tools-techniques-to-debug-jquery-event-handlers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - you're not stopping `propagation` and hence the first listener `$("table tr:not(:first-child)").click(function (e) {` is fired even when you click on the buttons and removing/hiding the row where the buttons are.

This will work.

```
$(".approve").click(function (e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you would like to approve this request?") == false) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
$(".deny").click(function (e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you would like to deny this request?") == false) {
        e.stopPropagation();

    }
});
$(".cancel").click(function (e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you would like to cancel this request?") == false) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/7Q79g/

Comment: You beat me by five seconds

Comment: @JustinKyleParton :P Yeh I hate it when that happens! Sorry buddy.

Comment: Thanks and really appreciated. Thanks Justin as well even if you were little late. :)

Comment: @fais Pleasure, glad it helped.